# Definition of Signalling and Screening Games?

Tags: game-theory, economics

I am currently studying some applied **screening** and **signalling** games in an advanced microeconomics course. Even though I understand the intuition and the idea of those games, I have not been able to find a formal and systematic way of defining **screening** and **signalling** games. Could anyone provide formal definitions for these two concepts? Also, some references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is asymmetric information, one party is informed and the other is not.

It is **screening** when the non-informed party takes action to discover some of the hidden information. F.i., an health insurer offers a menu of contracts to customers who have private information about their health status.

It is **signaling**  when the informed party takes action to reveal some of the hidden information. F.i., students take up challenging courses to provide evidence about their (privately known) quality to potential employers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I upvote it; but I do not accept it (at least yet) because it is not as formal as I need. A formal definition should state things like: are these games always 2 Player games? Are these games always two-move sequential games? How do we systematically define the strategies of informed and uniformed Players in these games? And so on...

Comment: @Héctor The amount of detail in my answer is proportional to the amount of detail in your question. If you like a more precise statement, please elaborate on the context of your question and ask a more detailed question.  (Thank you for the upvote.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my original question, I just could not find a **formal** definition of these screening and signalling games; and I was wondering if anyone in this site could provide such a **formal** definition. By formal I meant a full specification of the characteristics that make of a game signalling or screening. I'll keep searching, and I find a way to re-formulate my question I will. If time goes by and I don't find a way of re-phrasing the question and no more answers are provided, I'll accept yours.